# Считывать события нажатия клавиш при свернутом приложении

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Как продолжать считывать события, если приложение свернуто?

Я не хочу написать keylogger, мой вопрос связан с этой [темой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504539/%D0%A1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5)

Спасибо.

P.S. Скайп же способен как-то снимать с вебки, хотя окно свернуто.

P.S.S.  у меня как раз проблема с фоновыми задачами (дополнительно к считыванием клавиши). Камера перестает снимать, при переходе в свернутое состояние поток останавливается. Как создавать фоновые задачи?

Comment: Боюсь, этого не позволит операционка именно для того, чтобы нельзя было написать keylogger. Впрочем, подождём, может быть, кто-то знает ответ.

Comment: Но кейлоггеры существуют, а скайп как-то пишет при свернутом окне.

Comment: Существуют, конечно, но не под UWP. Насчёт скайпа хороший аргумент, да.

Comment: Шарп  не ограничен UWP. Хотя, тот скайп, что не десктоп, снимет и при свернутом отлично

Comment: Но вы-то написали тег UWP. Если вам нужно десктопное приложение, посмотрите в сторону клавиатурных хуков на WinAPI.

Comment: Тоже приложение ВКонтакте даже в свернутом состоянии (окно закрыто может быть) отслеживает сообщения и потом выводит уведомление.

Comment: Это обыкновенная фоновая задача. Но она не может опрашивать клавиатуру, на то она и фоновая.

Comment: А как создавать эти фоновые задачи?

Comment: Я не в курсе, но вот документация: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks

Comment: Там используется какие-то триггеры. Как я понял, фоновая задача начнет выполняться тогда, когда выполнится установленный триггер, но нельзя запустить фоновую задачу самостоятельно.

Comment: Не, должно быть возможно запустить и так.

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужен глобальный хоткей то в Win32 (не UWP) это возможно

[RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx)

Пример:

При старте

```
RegisterHotKey(g_hWnd, 1, MOD_CONTROL | MOD_WIN | MOD_ALT, VK_SPACE);
```

В обработчике

```
if(message == WM_HOTKEY)
{
    if (wParam == 1)
    {
    }
}
```

Для WPF нужно зарегистрировать hwnd hook для обработки WinAPI сообщений

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.addhook(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Мне без UWP никак.